# Angular select - value binding not working with dynamic options

Tags: angular

I'm trying to pre-select an option in an Angular select using the value attribute, when my option values are dynamically bound to strings.  I do not understand why the first example works, but the second does not.

This works...

```
<select [value]="'green'">
  <option value="">Select:</option>
  <option [value]="'red'">red</option>
  <option [value]="'green'">green</option>
  <option [value]="'blue'">blue</option>
</select>
```

... but this does not...

```
<select [value]="'blue'">
  <option value="">Select:</option>
  <option *ngFor="let color of colors" [value]="color"> 
        {{ color }}
  </option>
</select>
```

colors is a very simple array of strings...

```
colors = [ 'red', 'green', 'blue' ];
```

Here is a Stackblitz demonstrating the above...
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-sodbuz?file=src%2Fmain.component.html

The best I can come up with is that it's a timing thing.

Comment: try [ngValue] instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work because `*ngFor` rendering happens after initial value assignment. So if you change code to something like this it will work:

```
  <select [value]="selected">
     <option value="">Select:</option>
     <option *ngFor="let color of colors" [value]="color">
     {{ color }}
     </option>
  </select>

  selected: string | undefined = undefined;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.selected = 'red';
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use [(ngModel)] for dynamic bindings for example you can use ngModel like this

```
<select [(ngModel)]=”selectedColor">

  <option value="">Select:</option>

  <option *ngFor="let color of colors [value]="color"> {{ color }}</option>

</select>
```

On component.ts

```
setDefaultColor(){
 this.selectedColor = “blue”
}
```